# How to clear associative tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

How do i clear all elements in an associative table? I know of :

```
for key in pairs(t) do
    t[key] = nil
end
```

But that only clears the normal table.

Comment: What is the difference between associative table and normal table?

Comment: the normal table contains a set of values while the associative table contains keys and values.
sorry for not elaborating

Comment: Give an example of the table `t`. It seems that you are confused about the concept of arrays vs tables. Tables are also called associative arrays.

Comment: The concept you are missing is that in Lua, `t[key] = nil` removes both the key and the value. Neither values nor keys can be `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for key in pairs(t) do
    t[key] = nil
end
```

would clear any table entirely. I think you might be confusing it with

```
for key in ipairs(t) do
    t[key] = nil
end
```

this would clear the table of keys 1 till n where n is the first key for which t[n+1] == nil.

**Example:**

```
t = {
 [1] = 2,
 [2] = 3,
 [4] = 2,
 a = 1
}
```

First method would clear it, second method would leave keys 4 and a in it